# Get Multiple tables data at a time using joins in stored procedures in entity framework

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

Hi I am using EF6 in my mvc project and Db is sqlserver 2012.Now I want to use joins in stored procedures and i need to show these data in my view.

But I am unable to get those data. I want to know how to retrieve Multiple tables joins data in storedprocedures in entity framework.And My Project is Db First approach.

Regards,
Surya

Answer (score 0):

Instead of creating a stored procedure or a view at database level, you can use a ViewModel by combaining different models in it. Then return this ViewModel from Controller to the View. After changing data on the View then return this ViewModel to the Controller again. What you need is joining Entities in the Controller by using lambda expression then return the result as a ViewModel. Or you can get the ViewModel directly as below:

**Model:**

```
public class StudentViewModel
{
    public int ID { get; set; }

    public string InstituteName { get; set; }

    public string ContactNameSurname { get; set; } //Added to obtain ContactName and Surname on Index page

    public string CityName { get; set; } //Added to obtain City Name on Index page

    //Navigation property
    public virtual City City { get; set; }
}
```

**Controller:**

```
public ActionResult Index_Read([DataSourceRequest] DataSourceRequest request)
{
    var dataContext = repository.Students; 
    var result = dataContext.ToDataSourceResult(request, m => new 
    WebUI.Models.StudentViewModel
    {
        ID = m.ID,
        ContactNameSurname = m.ContactName + " " + m.ContactSurname,
        InstituteName = m.InstituteName,
        CityName = m.City.Name                  
    }
  );

  return Json(result, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

Hope this helps...